# how to get list of numbers by adding or subtracting given 4 numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am trying to get possible numbers from 1 to n, given 4 numbers. by adding or subbtracting 2 or more of the 4 numbers.

e.g. it goes into loop for numlist(1,2,3,16). Below is the code:

```
def numlist(a,b,c,d):  
    #user input of 4 numbers a,b,c,d
    # assigning variables value of -1. This will be used to provide -1 or +1 or 0
    p=-1 
    q=-1 
    r=-1
    s=-1
    count=0
    myarray=[]

    mysum=a+b+c+d  #sum of given 4 numbers


    for x in range(mysum):
        while count<mysum:
            if p<=1:
                if q<=1:
                    if r <=1:
                        if s<=1:
                            n1=p*a+q*b+r*c+s*d #number to be generated by adding/subtracting
                            s=s+1
                            #print(n1)
                            if n1>0 and (n1 in myarray)==False:
                                #print(n1)
                                myarray.append(n1) #add to myarray if number is positive and not already present
                                myarray.sort()  #sort myarray
                                count=count+1
                            if count==mysum:
                                 break
                        else:
                            s=-1

                        r=r+1
                    else:
                        r=-1

                    q=q+1
                else:
                    q=-1

                p=p+1
            else:
                p=-1

    print(len(myarray),'total')
    print(myarray)
numlist(1,3,4,14)
```

outputs

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]

but if numlist(1,3,4,19)
it keeps running without ending in output of array. only shows total.

where am I going wrong ?

Comment: If you merely want to solve the problem, then "jp" has given you a good solution.  If you want to know what's wrong with *your* code, then please rewrite it to be readable.  One- and two-letter variable names and magic constants make for hard reading, especially with no documentation at all.

Comment: This is my first time, I am learning and yes, looking for where this approach is going wrong

Comment: Okay; I'll keep an eye out for your rewrite.  `n1=p*a+q*b+r*c+s*d` is hardly self-explanatory, even in the given context.

Comment: I am trying to get combinations for the sum of numbers.
where p, q, r, s vary from -1 to+1. multiply this with a,b,c,d in combination to get a+b+c-d or 0a-1b+1c+1d or 1a-1b+1c+0d or -1a+1b+0c-1d and so on accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your given code fails to execute in several respects; this is not the code you used to produce the output you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should rethink your algorithm. Consider this:

```
from itertools import combinations

def numlist(lst):
    lst = lst + [-i for i in lst]
    result = set()
    for i in range(2, 5):
        result.update(sum(k) for k in combinations(lst, i))
    return sorted(i for i in result if i > 0)

numlist([1, 3, 4, 19])
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
```

Comment: Thank you JP
Gave me a new approach, Nice !

Comment: looks like with the same code, if I change the line
`while count < msum:`
to 
`for x in range(mysum):`
it works as expected and without going to loop!

Answer (score 0):

I did a little patch-up work, and found the high-level problem with your logic.

Your code goes into an infinite loop when the current value of `count` cannot be formed with the input values.  Your logic fails to increment `count` until it finds a way to create that value.  You spin through one combination after another of coefficients.

```
for x in range(mysum):
    print ("top of loop; x =", x)
    while count<mysum:
        print("count", count, "\tmysum", mysum, "\tcoeffs", p, q, r, s)
        if p<=1:
...
```